# Tensor Flow Object detection API notifications

Tags: tensorflow, timer, object-detection

Tensorflow 1.12.0
Python 3.5.0 
Windows 10

Hello all, I've created my own object detection model based on tensorflows object detection tutorial. I want to notify by SMS (via a service like twilio) when a object is detected, but I don't want to be notified by every frame of the same object class, instead I'd like to have a delay between text messages of objects i.e. every 5 seconds (at least) between every call. I've looked at threading and timer, but I fear that I'll restart the threading and timer every for call and was wondering if their is a more efficient way via the object detection API to accomplish this task. I know that I can print the actual class detected via

```
print [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
```

in the code

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ret, image_np = cap.read()
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)

      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (800,600)))
      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

but again, I don't want an overflow of text messages to my phone, and I don't want my script to pause neither.. if any suggestions can be given, I'd appreciate it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timer, try using a counter to count the frames in which it was detected.

and reset the counter every 10 frames or so.